# How to invert the order of the parameters of the post editing link "post edit" from WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

The default is: `example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=68105&action=edit`, but I need it as `example.com/wp-admin/post.php?action=edit&post=68105`.

Note that there is only a reversal of the parameters in the URL i.e. `action` and `postID`.

How can I invert them so that the `ID` is last in the URL? I've been reading about `link-template.php`.

Comment: Why do you want to reverse the parameters? Nothing should depend on the order of URL parameters.

Comment: It is only for aesthetics, the user needs to edit the post by the ID and the amount of posts is great. So users always edit the URL by adding the ID in the end, but in the case of that pattern there is a need to add "in the middle" and this is difficult for ordinary or novice users. They are confused with the question mark and the & symbol. I have seen in another site the order to be reversed, I do not know how they did it.

Comment: OK, so if you user is editing lots of posts and is able to edit the ID, why not just give them a URL with a placeholder ID which they can use. I'm just thinking that might be easier than changing the way wordpress works.

Comment: Or maybe a browser URL rewriter e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-rewriter/gpbblpbcnjdnnjdcdclojoonfmpoionh